# Location of Complex Roots

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Here is a problem I think dealing with Rouche's theorem:

How many roots does the equation 
$$
\frac{1}{2}e^z+z^4+1=0
$$
have in the left half plane $Re(z)<0$

I see that in order to have a root in this region we must have
$$
|z^4+1|<\frac{1}{2}
$$
but how does this give us a region in the left half plane?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The set $|z^4+1| = 1/2$ consists of four simple closed loops, two of which lie in the left half-plane.  Use Rouche's theorem on these two loops.

**More:**

The graph of $|z^4+1|$ looks like floating sheet which has been pinned to the ground at $z=e^{i\pi/4}$, $e^{i3\pi/4}$, $e^{i5\pi/4}$, and $e^{i7\pi/4}$:

[image]

The sets $|z^2+1| = \text{const}.$ are the level curves of this graph---you can think of them as the intersection of a flat surface with the graph.  If we choose $\epsilon > 0$ very small then the surface at height $\epsilon$ only intersects the graph very near to these four points:

[image]

and so the set $|z^4+1| = \epsilon$ consists of four simple closed loops around the points $e^{ik\pi/4}$ listed above.  By the minimum modulus principle, any component of $|z^4+1| \leq \epsilon$ must contain a zero of $z^4+1$, so you will not run into any rogue components appearing elsewhere as you increase $\epsilon$.

> **Exercise.**
>
> For $0 \leq a < 1$, show that the set $|z^4+1| = a$ consists of four components, each properly contained in the four quadrants of the complex plane.

Comment: I don't see how we get 4 simple closed loops.  I see the following
$$
|z^4+1| = |z-z_1||z-z_2||z-z_3||z-z_4| 
$$ 
What does this product represent graphically?  I dont think they are just simple closed loops, unless you have a stronger argument.

Comment: @EagerStudent I have added some more to the hint.

Comment: So because of this, there must be two roots in the left half plane.  This does not seem to even be a Rouche's Theorem problem then.

Comment: @EagerStudent, no, you know that **if** there are any roots of $\frac{1}{2}e^z+z^4+1=0$ in the left half-plane then they must lie inside the two components of the set $|z^4+1| < 1/2$.  You don't know for sure that there are two roots, one in each component, but it seems reasonable to suspect it because $z^4+1 = 0$ has two roots there and you're just perturbing it with the small quantity $e^z/2$.  You must use then use Rouché's theorem to formalize this argument.

Comment: Please elaborate.  Rouche's theorem requires us to use a find a bounded region where there is strict inequality on the boundary, then the upper bound and the sum of the upper and lower bound have the same number of zeros.  So we have that if there is a root in the LHP then it must satisfy
$$
|z^4+1|<1/2
$$
So how can we get 
$$
|z^4+1|<1/2|e^z|
$$
Or
$$
1/2|e^z|<|z^4+1|
$$

Comment: @EagerStudent, You're half a step away.  On the set $\{z \in \mathbb C\,\colon |z^4+1| = 1/2 \,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, \operatorname{Re}(z) < 0\}$ we have $$|z^4+1| = \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{2} |e^z| = \left|\frac{1}{2}e^z\right|,$$ which is the condition required by Rouché's theorem.

Comment: Boom! Done!  Thanks!

Comment: @EagerStudent, no problem `:)`.

Comment: Actually, another question.  For the exercise written above, how do we go about proving that.  because without the assistance of mathematica I am not sure what the region $|z^4+1| = a$ looks like.

Comment: @EagerStudent try showing that $|z^4+1| = a$ does not intersect either the real or the imaginary axis.